# A dance a song and an act

Tags: riddle

> At the start I am blaringly obvious,
>
> Get to know me and I will fade.
>
> A dance a song and an act,
>
> On the outside I am portrayed.
>
> As you see through me,
>
> The view is not pretty.
>
> The person I mask,
>
> You will not pity.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 5):

I don't think is actually the correct answer, but as it kind of fits the clues: are you…

> Fame

At the start I am blaringly obvious,

> Everyone knows the latest famous celebrity.

Get to know me and I will fade.

> The effect of fame fades as the mystique and novelty wear off.

A dance a song and an act,

> "Fame" the musical and song.

On the outside I am portrayed.

> The portrayal of fame/celebrity is often shallow and focused on the external factors (outside). Also, posters, tabloids, etc.

As you see through me,
The view is not pretty.

> Beneath their facade, famous people are not so perfect.

The person I mask,
You will not pity.

> Fame masks the real person, but people don't pity them for it (and indeed can critique them quite mercilessly ,i.e., without pity).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are

> A scent.

At the start I am blaringly obvious,

Get to know me and I will fade.

> When you first encounter a scent, it is very strong. But when you get used to it, you can go "nose blind" and not smell it as strongly anymore. (["Olfactory fatigue," Wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5rVt.jpg))

A dance a song and an act,

> There is a perfume (branded for Shakira) called "Dance", a classic Prince Matchabelli perfume called "Wind Song" (the one that "stays on my mind"), and a cologne (for men) from Avon called "Class Act".

On the outside I am portrayed.

> They look like this: [image: Perfumes]

As you see through me,

The view is not pretty.

> This could be interpreted two ways. 1. Looking through perfume, the view is distorted: [image: Looking through perfume bottle]. 2. Some of the ingredients in perfume are...less pretty than the whole. (See, for example, ["5 Repulsive Ingredients in Your Perfume or Cologne"](http://www.care2.com/causes/5-repulsive-ingredients-in-your-perfume-or-cologne.html).)

The person I mask,

> Fragrances have been historically used to "mask" unpleasant odors, and also in medieval times were used in literal masks as a (supposed) protection against disease. (["Plague Doctor", Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plague_doctor#Costume))

You will not pity.

> [This guy (Wikimedia "Plague Doctor")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plague_doctor#/media/File:Paul_F%C3%BCrst,_Der_Doctor_Schnabel_von_Rom_(Holl%C3%A4nder_version).png) would inspire fear, rather than pity; modern users of [deodorant (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Deodorant&oldid=739135907) are also less likely to be pitied than those who have body odor issues (and someone wearing too much fragrance is more likely to inspire annoyance than pity).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are:

> A face

At the start I am blaringly obvious,

> When you see a face it is instantly recognized as such

Get to know me and I will fade.

> Faces change over time, so the original memory of the face will fade

A dance a song and an act,

> Faces move and contort(dance) and which convey meaning (song) and can be used to deliberately to tell a story (act)

On the outside I am portrayed.

> Face is on the outside

As you see through me,

> You see from behind or through your face

The view is not pretty.

> Faces are pretty to look at, but the beauty can't be seen while looking through them

The person I mask, You will not pity.

> Faces mask yourself, and you wouldn't pity yourself for that.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly:

> Condensation

At the start I am blaringly obvious,

> At the start of the day when you get up  it is all over the windows

Get to know me and I will fade.

> If you wait then it will fade as the day gets warmer

A dance a song and an act,

> It can make patterns on the window?

On the outside I am portrayed.

> The condensation is on the inside so from outside it can't be rubbed off

As you see through me,
The view is not pretty.

> It makes it hard to see through the window

The person I mask,
You will not pity.

> No idea

Answer (score 1):

What about:

> Physical beauty

At the start I am blaringly obvious,

> What's the first thing you see about a person?

Get to know me and I will fade.

> Beauty itself fades with time, as well as your perception of a person as beautiful (you don't notice as much).

A dance a song and an act,

> Beauty dazzles the senses.

On the outside I am portrayed.

> Visual beauty is clearly on the outside.

As you see through me, The view is not pretty.

> As you start to see the real person behind the beauty, they are probably nothing close to the judgment you made based on their looks.

The person I mask, You will not pity.

> Nobody feels badly for beautiful people - they have too much of an easy life already.  Even if their struggles or failings are not their fault, most would still not pity them.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,  you are:

> OPERA ARTS

At the start I am blaringly obvious

> when start an opera, I see that music is so loud

Get to know me and I will fade

> After that, the sound is smaller and smaller

A dance a song and an act

> Character will dance in opera, they will sing and act so much

On the outside I am portrayed

> Opera would describe a story

As you see through me,

The view is not pretty.
The person I mask
You will not pity.

> This clue I have not enough English to describe.

Sorry for my bad English, but when read this question, I think about Mr.2 in One Piece and Opera arts ^^

Comment: Can you explain why, and explain all the clues in the riddle?

Comment: Opera the browser or Opera the type of song

Comment: So sorry for missing that. My English is not good so I answer which I think about.